# Way to ensure that string is in JSON format

Tags: json, ansible

In an Ansible task I'd like to test if string is json prior to use it with from_json.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'tojson': u'{{ notjson | from_json}}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you just do a `set_fact` block with `from_json`, and use the success/failure of that block to determine if the  string is JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Invalid JSON will fail. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        json_parsed: "{{ json_str|from_json }}"
      vars:
        json_str: 'invalid JSON'
```

```yaml
TASK [set_fact] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'json_parsed': '{{ json_str|from_json }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
  
    The error appears to be in '/export/scratch/tmp/test-145.yml': line 21, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
        - set_fact:
          ^ here
```

It's possible to handle the error. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        json_parsed: "{{ json_str|from_json }}"
      vars:
        json_str: 'invalid JSON'
      ignore_errors: true
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.msg }}"
      when: result.failed
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'json_parsed': '{{ json_str|from_json }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
  
    The error appears to be in '/export/scratch/tmp/test-145.yml': line 11, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
        - set_fact:
          ^ here
```

---

- Ansible filter [*from_json*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L2147) is wrapper to Python [*json.loads*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- See [*Error handling in playbooks*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)
- See [*meta*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#ansible-builtin-meta-execute-ansible-actions) on how to end a play or host gracefully.

Comment: ignore_errors :-) ... Thank you Vlado, very much appreciated. That's what I was trying to do and failed :-(